# How to keep the mask character displayed if the value is valid and remove the mask character if there is no input value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When the input text of the MaskedEditExtender is not focused, I would like to keep the mask character displayed if the value is valid and remove the mask character if there is no input value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a text box, you can use the OnClick Event to dynamically generate the MaskedEditExtender, and then the OnTextChanged event to check if there is an input value still. If there is then you keep the control, if not then you remove it.